# iOS Ad-Tracker blockers. Who is your champion?

Tags: iphone, ios, network

Firefox Focus? BlockBear? Brave AdBlocker?
Another specialized browser? DuckDuckGo? Ghostery?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 3):

`1Blocker` is my favorite. It blocks most ads I come across.

Additionally it blocks many cookie notices, comments, anti-adblock notifications, twitter and facebook widgets, lets me whitelist sites I want to see ads on and also syncs seamlessly with my mac via iCloud.